# JsDoc union type with objects not working

Tags: javascript, typescript, jsdoc

I'm at my wits end with this. It seems like it should work, I've been wrestling with it for hours, but I'm not sure what's wrong. This is the smallest example I could come up with. I even have a type guard.

```js
/** @typedef {{ a: string }} TypeA*/
/** @typedef {{ b: string }} TypeB*/
/** @typedef {(TypeA | TypeB) } TypeC */

/** @type {TypeC} */
let typeC;

console.log(typeC.b) // autocompletion for property b doesn't work
```

I get the error:

```
Property 'b' does not exist on type '{ a: string; } | { b: string; }'.
  Property 'b' does not exist on type '{ a: string; }'.ts(2339)
```

Comment: Not sure what your setup is, but whenever I have issues with jsdoc, it's usually because the comments weren't updated with changes. If you just remove the jsdoc and let your IDE re-generate them, it will help you figure out what it should be/what the issue is

Comment: I'm trying to add some type safety in my ide to javascript since i'm not using typescript.

Comment: Why'd you specify typescript as a tag then?

Comment: Because the jsdoc types are being processed by the typescript-language-server.

Comment: So you are using typescript

Comment: I suppose what I meant by "not using typescript" is that I'm not writing typescript. But I am using the typescript compiler, and I didn't find a  typescript-language-server- tag, so I tagged it typescript.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Edit: The root of this issue is my misunderstanding of the union operator `|` and how TypeScript narrows types. Tsserver, the typescript language service, is what was interpreting these JSDoc comments and providing language services like autocomplete. I'll write some TypeScript to explain properly how types were working in this situation.

Given this situation:

```js
type TypeA = { a: string };
type TypeB = { b: string };
type TypeC = TypeA | TypeB;

const typeC: TypeC = { /* omitted */ };
```

`typeC` could either be `TypeA` or `TypeB`, but we don't know which one. So, TypeScript isn't going to let us access `typeC.a` or `typeC.b` because we haven't written any code that narrows down `typeC` to either `TypeA` or `TypeB`. That's why the autocomplete isn't working. And that's why in my previous answer below duck typing, or using a type guard that asserts a variable is `TypeB`, works.

So with a [union](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#union-types), you need to narrow down that type at run time to be able to safely access the properties. Possibly by checking whether a set of properties unique to one of the possible types is present, or an assertion using `as`, or something else.

Another approach is instead to use an [intersection](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/objects.html#intersection-types). An intersection says a type has all the properties of both types. This would work:

```js
type TypeC = TypeA & TypeB;
```

Then we can access `typeC.a` and `typeC.b`.

Below is my previous answer, kept for historical reasons.

---

I found that a jsdoc style type guard lets me access the properties of TypeC if I am able to duck type it as TypeB.

```js
/** @typedef {{ a: string }} TypeA*/
/** @typedef {{ b: string }} TypeB*/
/** @typedef {(TypeA | TypeB) } TypeC */

/**
 * @param {*} value
 * @returns {value is TypeB}
 */
function typeIsB(value) {
  return true;
}

/** @type {TypeC} */
let typeC;

if (typeIsB(typeC)) {
  console.log(typeC.b) // no error, autocomplete works when typing typeC.b
}
```

Screenshot of autocomplete working:

[image]

Comment: For those stumbling onto this, this is almost certainly not a standard JSDoc feature but is part of Typescript, specifically it's a type predicate see https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/narrowing.html#using-type-predicates and https://code.visualstudio.com/updates/vJanuary#_javascript-salsa-preview

Answer (score 1):

I think you are looking for the [intersection](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/unions-and-intersections.html#intersection-types) of A and B, not the union. Here is the typescript code for your issue fixed:

```js
interface A {
  a: string;
}

interface B {
  b: string;
}

type C = A & B;
```

Comment: I want TypeC to be TypeA or TypeB, not both. AFAIK, intersections guarantee the presence of each type's properties. I could do intersections, if I can someone document that it's either one or the other, not both.

Comment: I think my code example in my question was poorly written and misleading. I think my implementation does imply I want an intersection. Sorry about that. I've edited it to be more clear, and also added an answer of what worked for me.

Answer (score 1):

When you say that a value is of type A or B, the typescript compiler does not know which type of value is refrenced by that variable.

```
/** @typedef {{ a: string }} TypeA*/
/** @typedef {{ b: string }} TypeB*/
/** @typedef {(TypeA | TypeB) } TypeC */

/** @type {TypeC} */
let typeC;

console.log(typeC.b) // autocompletion for property b doesn't work
```

You need a condition to determine the actual type of the value referenced by typeC. For example:

```
if ('a' in typeC) {
    console.log(typeC.a) // autocompletion for property a works       
} else {
    console.log(typeC.b) // autocompletion for property b works       
}
```

Comment: Wow! I didn't know of `'a' in obj`! I always did `if (obj.a) {}`, which works but sometimes yields a nasty `property "a" doesn't exist on object "obj"` error...